# Flask app can't find google module

Tags: python, flask, google-api

I'm using a virtual environment to run a flask app. When I run `pip freeze`, I get the following:

```
google-api-core==0.1.1
google-auth==1.2.1
google-cloud-core==0.28.0
google-cloud-speech==0.30.0
google-gax==0.15.16
googleapis-common-protos==1.5.3
```

However, during run time, I get the following error:

```
    from google.cloud import speech
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google'
```

I'm using the google speech APIs. They work just fine when I run them locally. I don't understand why the app can't find the modules even though they're listed as installed. Can someone suggest a fix? I've tried doing `pip install google`, and it downloaded a bunch of other stuff, but still no fix.

Comment: Can you show your directory and file structure? You may have a file or folder called "google" which is interfering with the package import.

Answer (score 1):

So there are a lot of places where the error could be coming from. Could you please provide more details?

For example, which python version are you using? Python 2 or 3? If you are calling the wrong interpreter you need to type

```
python3 -m pip install
```

or

```
python3 -m pip install
```

accordingly.

Secondly are you using conda? If so, you need to use

```
conda install
```

instead of `pip install`. You can find out by typing `which python` in your terminal.

Third, are you sure you installed the google module correctly? If not try using

```
pip install google --user
```

and see if that works.

Lastly, are you installing the correct package? Because I believe for the speech api you need to do:

```
pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, removing the virtual environment and reinstalling all the dependencies worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to add to your flask.py the path to modules you already installed:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/")
import google
import gspread
```

That worked like magic to me at AWS.